# Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr

Tags: node.js, next.js

Have this Warning in terminal, having issue tracking down the source or the actual reason / cause of it.

```
(node:37770) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:37770) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
```

Not much information to provide unfortunately. I understand it's something with Node, but no clue how to solve it. https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html

Node -v `stable 8.9.0 (bottled), HEAD`

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.0",
    "babel-plugin-wrap-in-js": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "compression": "^1.7.1",
    "cookie": "^0.3.1",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "firebase": "^4.6.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.4.3",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^2.0.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "lusca": "^1.5.2",
    "next": "^4.1.4",
    "next-redux-wrapper": "^1.3.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "now-logs": "0.0.7",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "orm": "^4.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "raw-loader": "^1.0.0-beta.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",
    "react-stripe-elements": "^1.2.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.2.1",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "session-file-store": "^1.1.2",
    "styled-jsx": "^2.1.2",
    "timeme.js": "^2.0.3",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems an issue related with Node 8 and the `session-file-store` module.

https://github.com/valery-barysok/session-file-store/issues/65

Comment: Thanks!  That seems to be the cause. Will keep a eye on that thread to see if it will result in fixing the issue

Answer (score 6):

for above warning use

```
var crypto = require('crypto'),
algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr',
password = 'test@1234';
var iv = Buffer.from(Array.prototype.map.call(Buffer.alloc(16), () => {return Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)}));
var key = Buffer.concat([Buffer.from(password)], Buffer.alloc(32).length);
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm,password,iv)
```

in the createCipheriv method, we need to create one buffer for iv and one buffer for the key which contains password

instead of

```
var crypto = require('crypto'),
algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr',
password = 'test@1234';
var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm,password)
```

while converting your data to cipher.
it will remove the warning

Comment: in some cases, while converting text into cipher it asks for the key but in our method createCipheriv we are not using it so it's ok to not declaring it

Comment: The reviewers seem to be rejecting a proposed edit, but just to help anyone using this code, the bottom line of the top code snippet needs to be: var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm,key,iv); where 'key' is substituted for 'password'.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue and after running through this
[node issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/13801)
and looking at the bottom of [this section](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipher_algorithm_password_options)
it looks like using aes-256-ctr without a random input to shake it up isn't recommended.  After updating this to another algorithm the error went away.

I'm not sure which of your deps may be throwing this if you don't use crypto within your code.  It may turn up searching for `createCipher` or `aes-256-ctr`.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use the createCipheriv method